# SSRS 2016 RDL view in HTML5?

Tags: sql-server, html, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I am aware that SSRS 2016 provides RDL to be viewed in HTML5 as "Preview" version in admin portal, but is there a way to view the RDL in my MVC .HTML view without using asp.net report viewer controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe approach if you don't like ReportViewer Control.
Here is the example of URL to embed:
https://reportserver/reports/mobilereport/Marketing%20Scorecard?rs:Embed=true

Look here for more information:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/03/18/sql-server-2016-rc1-whats-new-in-reporting-services/

Answer (score 0):

The embedded html viewer with iframe works great with integrated auth, how about making it work with custom auth/FBA forms based Auth?